# unable to install maven in windows : "'mvn' is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file"

Tags: maven, cmd, environment-variables

i followed and referred the steps shared previously , but still finding the same problem ,"'mvn' is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 2):

Erase the backslash in front of the `%MAVEN_HOME%`.

Comment: did that still the same

Comment: You have restarted the cmd? If the cmd came from a Windows Explorer, have you restarted that as well?

Comment: I did a system restart as well..  Still the same problem

Comment: I guess you just make a simple typo somewhere ... because everything looks alright.